# Вводится знаковое целое длинное число(32 бита) А. Необходимо циклически сдвинуть А вправо на n бит

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Нашёл программу выполняющую условие моей задачи. Нужно организовать ввод самого числа А и ввод числа n. Ко всему этому мне подсказали недостаток данной программы. она выполняет действия в битовом типе данных,а необходимо использовать int.

```
include <iostream>
include <bitset>

using namespace std;

const unsigned int BYTE = 10; // количество разрядов
const unsigned int STEP = 2;  // на сколько шагов нужно будет сдвинуть

int main() {
    bitset<BYTE> bit(106), part1, part2, result;

    cout << "bit\t" << bit << endl; // исходное число

    // результат будет составлен из двух частей
    part1 = bit >> STEP; // первая часть, два сдвига вправо
    cout << "part1\t" << part1 << endl;

    part2 = bit << BYTE - STEP; // вторая часть, восемь сдвигов влево (десять разрядов числа минус два шага)
    cout << "part2\t" << part2 << endl;

    result = part1 | part2; // объеденияем части

    cout << "result\t" << result << endl; // результат объединения частей
    system("pause");


}
```

Предполагаю,что нужно заменить эту часть на ввод данных в main.

```
const unsigned int BYTE = 10; // количество разрядов
const unsigned int STEP = 2;  // на сколько шагов нужно будет сдвинуть
```

И не использовать ничего кроме `include <iostream>`. нельзя использовать `include <bitset>` и `include <limits.h>`

Comment: И объясните мне,новичку на данном сайте. За что люди ставят -балл к вопросу. человек ни прокомментировал ничего,просто поставил и всё. А я теперь не могу вопросы задавать. Вроде ж всё понятно объяснил.

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что не сможете вопросы задавать? Кто то не понел вопрос и посчитал ненужным разобраться в вопросе, это не может вам мешать задавать вопрос

Comment: Вам нужна операция rotate? Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/best-practices-for-circular-shift-rotate-operations-in-c) есть варианты

Comment: @ARHhovsepyan сам сайт выдал предупреждение,что не могу задавать вопросы.

Comment: Также есть [стандартный алгоритм](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate), надо только правильно представить ваше число

Comment: @cppquestions а что-то типа есть на русском)?

Comment: @СOM достаточно вместо `en` поставить `ru` - https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate

Comment: @cppquestions спасибо,ща будем разбираться)

Comment: циклический сдвиг не означает  выполнять сдвиг в цикле, а означает, что  биты с конца идут в начало.  Я тоже может не теми словами выразился, ну например, если циклически сдвигать 1011101 на 2 вправо, то последные 0 и 1 окажутся в начале и получится 0110111

Comment: @ARHovsepyan о господи,спасибо,мой спаситель! я этого не знал,значит по сути программа выполняет свои задачи,осталось только реализовать ввод А и N

Comment: Ну да конечно, если не учесть, что  есть варианты и получше...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan данный вариант больше остальных подходит под мой...уровень знания языка,он самый понятный и я преподавателю(которому буду это сдавать) смогу объяснить программу

Comment: Скорее всего в условии задачи подразумевается тип данных `long` (а не `bitset<BYTE>`)

Comment: @avp вполне вероятно

Comment: тогда BYTE = sizeof(long)  и ваш результат будет result.to_ulong(), а не  result

Comment: Вам что, до сих пор данный ответ не подходит?

Comment: @MBo нет и причины объяснены в описании

Comment: Мешает `limits.h`? сделайте `nb  = 32`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, вы уже сами нашли решение.

На всякий случай, для типа данных `long`, программа вместе с вводом и проверками может выглядеть как-то так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>

using namespace std;
int main () {
  cout << "Rotate long `a` rigth, enter value of `a` and shift:\n";

  long a, n;
  size_t nb = sizeof(a) * CHAR_BIT;

  cout << "long a is " << nb << " bits long\n";

  while (cin >> a >> n) {
    if (n > -1 && n < nb) {
      cout << "a = " << dec << a << " 0x" << hex << a << '\n';

      // это собственно вращение
      // cast к unsigned необходим, чтобы при сдвиге влево знаковый разряд не распространялся
      a = (((unsigned long)a) >> n) | (a << (nb - n));

      cout << "after rotr a = " << dec << a << " 0x" << hex << a << '\n';
    } else
      cout << "wrong shift value " << n << '\n';
  }

}
```

Comment: А возможно выполнить данную программу без дополнительных библиотек по типу "limits.h"? просто пришло время сдачи,а препод меня хорошенько проучил,за использование дополнительной библиотеки.

Comment: и здесь получается сдвиг влево,а необходимо вправо

Comment: @COM: Во-первых, `<limits.h>` - это никакая не библиотека. Во-вторых, циклический сдвиг влево и циклический сдвиг вправо - одно и то же. Вопрос только, на сколько сдвигать.